# React Native Expo MQTT Connection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mqtt

I want to make MQTT connection with React Native expo. Existing libraries did not work with expo. Is there a library you use? Can you help me?

Anyone have previous experience with this issue?

Comment: What libraries did you try? What didn’t work with each one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.